# $f=0$ $a.e$ implies that $f\equiv 0$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $U\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be a connected open set, and let $f:U\to\mathbb{R}$ be a function of class $\mathcal{C}^1(U)$ such that $f=0$ $a.e$ (almost everywhere). How does one prove that $f\equiv0$ ?

Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Try to show that $f= 0$ on a dense subset of $U$, then use continuity (differentiability is not needed)

Answer (score 4):

Assume that $f$ is not equal to $0$ everywhere. Therefore, there exists some $x_0$ such that $f(x_0) > 0$ (without loss of generality).

Now, try and find some ball around $x_0$ on which $f$ is not equal to $0$. Continuity of $f$ should be enough for this. Since the ball has a nonzero measure, $f$ is not $0$ a.e.

Comment: Why is connectedness needed?

Comment: @learnmore I don't see why it would be needed.

Comment: okay good work +1

Comment: I think connectedness is needed. for example let $U=N^n\subset R^n$ and $f(x)=1$ then $f$ is continuous

Comment: @RaziehNoori Your example is not an open set. I think connectedness is not needed, because once we have $x_0$, we can simply take a ball $B(x_0, \delta)$ for some small enough $\delta$ such that the ball is a subset of $U$. Then we only focus on the ball and the behaviour of the function in the ball, in which we find a smaller ball on which $f$ has no roots.

Comment: quite right, thank you very much